# MS office 2016 excel paste values with transpose

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste, microsoft-excel-2016, paste, transpose

Is it possible to make this paste option (paste only values with transpose at the same time). As it shown on the schreenshot:

[image: paste only values with transpose]

and having one button for this option in drop-down menu here:

[image: excel drop-down menu]

Comment: you could create a macro that would do it in your personal workbook, then create a button for it in the ribbon that fires that macro

Comment: @User91504 Yes, I could, but I have zero experience (or only negative) with MS office macros. And this will be working only in one document or it is possible to make working in all excel documents?

Comment: yeah you can do it accross any work sheet, i dont havfe excel 2016 so i cant make the macro for you, but google how to record a macro, you dont need to write it

Comment: @User91504 yes! it is much easier than I have experienced before (and also it is working).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks User91504, for encouraging me to try MS macrosing.

The working solution has very simple code:

```
Sub Paste_transpose()
'
' Paste_transpose Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Offset.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

And there is possibility to add keys combination for this macro - no need to add any buttons anywhere.

Comment: AWESOME stuff ! also check out these 2 links https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-66c97ab3-11c2-44db-b021-ae005a9bc790     http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-assign-macros-to-the-ribbon-and-the-quick-access-toolbar-in-excel-2013/

Comment: @User91504 Thanks! Now it will be working in all my computers. And using keyboard shortcut is much faster. At the beginning I thought there is possibility to customize paste options to make favorite.